# откуда $_POST и $_GET в php читают входные данные?

Tags: php, c++, сервер, backend

Я пишу свой небольшй HTTP-сервер на с++. В нем мне нужно обрабатывать динамические запросы. Я открываю дочерний процесс, запускаю в нем скрипт и отдаю std::out(которым является html текст) отработавшего скрипта клиенту. Вопрос состоит в том, как мне передать входные данные в этот скрипт? В моем случае входными данными является get или post зопросы, из которых php-скрипт по средствам $_POST и $_GET может брать информацию о переменных. Я пытался сделать это, положив запросы в std::in, но у меня ничего не вышло, методы  $_POST и $_GET не видят запрос.

Comment: передай get это url адрес с параметрами http://mydomen.ru/index.php?param1=123&param2=1234 и лови это так <?php  $res1=$_GET["param1"]; print_r($res);

Comment: Вам нужно передавать ключи и значения, или только значения? В любом случае, вы можете использовать консольные параметры и доставать их через getopt (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.getopt.php)

Comment: А сделать это по средствам с++ никак нельзя? нужно создавать дополнительные скрипты для заполнения суперглобальных ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в c/c++ тоже есть getopts (http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)